# Вопрос по слитному и раздельному написанию слов

Tags: словообразование

Как пишется мало летучий - слитно или раздельно?

Answer (score 1):

Малолетучий - это сложное слово, пишется слитно

Answer (score 0):

Малолетучий - термин, образованный сращением наречия и прилагательного (малолетучий газ, жидкость). Термины - вещь неустойчивая и могут распадаться на исходные части. Можно представить такое выражение: мало летучий в обычных условиях газ.

Малолетучий, разумеется, сложное слово. Но сложные слова могут писаться не только слитно, но и через дефис, также их нужно отличать от словосочетаний с раздельным написанием, например: малознакомые места - мало знакомые нам места.